# Web Media Queries for Smartwatches

Tags: php, jquery, html, sony-smartwatch

I'd like to get my hands on webdev for smartwatches. Are there any media queries that identify them? CSS viewport definitions? etcetera?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you talking about having a web view showing on the smartwatch?

Comment: yep, like, desktop/tabletVertical/tabletHorizontal/Mobile and then, as an even smaller viewport, watch.

Comment: ok I see. So if you are talking about Android Wear it seems that android does not support webkit as stated here: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your input, Robert! So how does the Wear Internet Browser (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appfour.wearbrowser) Work? Are the websites rendered on the smartphone and then pushed to the watch?